# How to draw a square with SDL 2.0?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I would like to do something simple like draw a square on the screen using C and SDL. The example that I copied is not working.

```
//Get window surface
SDL_Surface *screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

//Fill the surface white
SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));

//create a square
SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, SDL_Rect(0,0,100,100), SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00));
```

It correctly fills the screen white, but fails on the call to `SDL_Rect`:

```
error: expected expression before ‘SDL_Rect’
```

How do I correctly draw a square using SDL 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by [Zach Stark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19732066/48523), `SDL_FillRect` does not take an `SDL_Rect` as an argument. Rather, it takes a pointer to an `SDL_Rect`. By prefixing the variable with an ampersand (`&`), you pass only a reference (a pointer) to the original variable. However, I could not get Zach's code sample to work in my C program. The following uses a different syntax for creating an `SDL_Rect` but it worked for me.

```
// create a black square
SDL_Rect rect = {0, 0, 100, 100}; // x, y, width, height
SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, &rect, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00));
```

Answer (score 5):

`SDL_FillRect` does not take an `SDL_Rect` as an argument; it takes a pointer to `SDL_Rect`.

```
//Create a square
SDL_Rect rect(0,0,100,100);
SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, &rect, SDL_MapRGB(...))
```

That is why when you fill with white you can pass `NULL` to the function. `NULL` is not of type `SDL_Rect`, but it is a pointer, so the compiler is fine with it.

Comment: Ah, okay. What's the difference between `&` and `*`?

Comment: Also, I'm getting an error on the line with `rect(0,0,100,100)`: `error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant`. Is this the way to create a SDL_Rect in C?

Comment: @Andrew When declaring, `*` says that the variable is a *pointer* and `&` says that it is a *reference*. On an already declared variable, `*` means *the value that the variable (the pointer) points to* and `&` means *the address of the variable*. These are pretty basic C/C++ stuff; I suggest you to understand these concepts better before diving into SDL.

Comment: When doing this i get the error `error: no matching function for call to ‘SDL_Rect::SDL_Rect(int, int, int, int)’` when creating the rect, why?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SDL_RenderDrawRect](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderDrawRect?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryRender%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29).