# SDL2/SDL problem on getting next shape with different color in window

Tags: c++, sdl

The problem I got is by pressing the right arrow key, a square of different colors will appear, press the right arrow again the same thing to happen till the window is filled with 20 squares. After which, I press the left arrow key and one by one the squares will disappear descendingly till the last square. I managed to get the 1st box but am confused and uncertain on how to get proceed on getting the next square.

Below are the codes I had written.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 640;

enum KeyPressSurfaces {
    KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT,
    KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT,
    KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_RIGHT,
    KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL
};

SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;
SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;
SDL_Surface* gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL ];
SDL_Surface* gCurrentSurface = NULL;

int main( int argc, char* args[] ) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1");
    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Muhammad Hilmi Bin Sazali Q1771290", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                                               SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 
                                               SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    //gKeyPressSurfaces[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT] = SDL_LoadBMP("left.bmp");
    //gKeyPressSurfaces[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_RIGHT] = SDL_LoadBMP("right.bmp");

    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event e;
    gCurrentSurface = gKeyPressSurfaces[ KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT ];

    while( !quit ) {
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 ) {
            if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
                quit = true;
            else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                switch (e.key.keysym.sym) {
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    gCurrentSurface = gKeyPressSurfaces[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT];
                    break;

                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    gCurrentSurface = gKeyPressSurfaces[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_RIGHT];
                    break;
                }
            }
        

        // background - white
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF );
        SDL_RenderClear( gRenderer );
        // orange square
        SDL_Rect fillRect = { SCREEN_WIDTH / -4, SCREEN_HEIGHT / -4, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 };
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 255, 165, 000, 255 );        
        SDL_RenderFillRect( gRenderer, &fillRect );
        // green square
        //SDL_Rect fillRect = { SCREEN_WIDTH / -4, SCREEN_HEIGHT / -4, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 };
        //SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 39, 139, 34, 255 );        
        //SDL_RenderFillRect( gRenderer, &fillRect );
        // blue square
        //SDL_Rect fillRect = { SCREEN_WIDTH / -4, SCREEN_HEIGHT / -4, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 };
        //SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 0, 255, 255, 255 );        
        //SDL_RenderFillRect( gRenderer, &fillRect );
        // purple square
        //SDL_Rect fillRect = { SCREEN_WIDTH / -4, SCREEN_HEIGHT / -4, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 };
        //SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 127, 0, 255, 255 );        
        //SDL_RenderFillRect( gRenderer, &fillRect );
        // red square
        //SDL_Rect fillRect = { SCREEN_WIDTH / -4, SCREEN_HEIGHT / -4, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 };
        //SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 255, 0, 0, 255 );      
        //SDL_RenderFillRect( gRenderer, &fillRect );

        SDL_RenderPresent( gRenderer );
        SDL_BlitSurface( gCurrentSurface, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL; ++i) {
        SDL_FreeSurface(gKeyPressSurfaces[i]);
        gKeyPressSurfaces[i] = NULL;
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(gRenderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    gWindow = NULL;
    gRenderer = NULL;
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730964/how-to-draw-a-square-with-sdl-2-0

Comment: yeah, that is more on getting the exact square shape I believe, this is more on getting the next step of getting the shape at the keypress

Comment: In that case you need to write some sort of square drawing engine, that allows it to only draw the correct number of squares based on a global integer.